# Create new reference to array with different length

Tags: c#, arrays

Given some array:

```
int[] array = new int[8000];
```

Is it possible to refer to a new array such that:

```
int[] array2 = Array.SameReferenceDifferentLength(array, 4000);
// array1.Length == 8000;
// array2.Length == 4000;
// &array2[0] == &array[0];
```

Comment: Can't you just iterate into the first one to get the new one?

Comment: The short answer is "no", but you can always emulate this yourself by wrapping an array and maintaining your own "length" which differs for different wrappers of the same array.

Comment: @Cameron That's not really true. The .NET `ArraySegment` struct is for exactly the OP's scenario.

Comment: @Timothy: I stand corrected! Upvote for you :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [ArraySegment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1hsbd92d.aspx) struct:

```
var a = new string[] { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e" };

var b = new ArraySegment<string>(a, 1, 3);

foreach (var s in b)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

This makes a shallow reference to the specified range of the array. That is, it doesn't copy the array data.

If you want to index an `ArraySegment<T>`, you can cast it to a `IList<T>` then use the indexer provided by that interface.

---

To mimic the code in your question:

```
int array = new int[8000];
var array2 = new ArraySegment<int>(array, 0, 4000);
//array.Length == 8000
//array2.Count == 4000
//array == array2.Array
```

Comment: Although, not exactly what I was looking for (I was really hoping for a variable of type `int[];` `ArraySegment<int>.Array` returns the original array), I think the answer fits the question.


The more I think about it, this type of nonsense is probably only possible in unsafe code using fixed pointers. It would be a nightmare if the CLR had to track whether any portion of an array was referenced in order to collect it.

Comment: @Imisnew2 That's exactly the reason the `ArraySegment<T>` might seem a little strange. This is the best you can do without entering the land of unsafeness. You could certainly use unsafe C# code with pointers to get a more direct control - this is something I've actually done before for some image processing.